# Importing JSON string to java

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert a JSON string array to a java array?

For example something similar to this http://api.soundrop.fm/spaces/XJTt3mXTOZpvgmOc

I need to fetch the currently playing and artist values.

Comment: Are you writing a Java program that is supposed to read a string from a textfile similar to the one linked in your post? Please elaborate.

Comment: I assume that because seeing as it was outputted by a webpage it seems lightly, evidently I was wrong. And no text file, I have a script that fetches the linked url and returns it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to serialize the JSON into a Java object.

Then you can get the [JSONArray](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html) from that object and stroe it in its own array.

**Example:**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray owners = (JSONArray) json.get("owners");

Iterator<String> iterator = owners.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wr3pWSGt54GlRiEL
XJU7ZqZ3MYrQncIw
```

**Formatted JSON:**

```
{
   "_id":"XJTt3mXTOZpvgmOc",
   "cover_picture":"http://images.soundrop.fm/spaces/XJTt3mXTOZpvgmOg/5I3f6HGSSob6c1TTzK8vHg",
   "creator":"Wr3pWSGt54GlRiEL",
   "description":"Radio for Okicraft minecraft server!\nwww.okicraft.com",
   "display_name":"Molly's Bang'n Tunes FM AKA Okicraft Radio :D",
   "display_picture":"http://images.soundrop.fm/spaces/XJTt3mXTOZpvgmOg/AiTQDQBYGg1wesnhFVLao",
   "owners":[
      "Wr3pWSGt54GlRiEL",
      "XJU7ZqZ3MYrQncIw"
   ],
   "parameters":{
      "soundrop:chat":{
         "version":2
      },
      "soundrop:membership":{
         "version":2
      },
      "soundrop:playlist":{
         "version":2,
         "mode":"open"
      }
   },
   "presence":{
      "soundrop:chat":{

      },
      "soundrop:membership":{
         "members_live_count":0,
         "members_total_count":189,
         "members_max_count":8,
         "members_max_date":"2014-02-01T19:33:29Z",
         "members_summary":[

         ]
      },
      "soundrop:playlist":{
         "current":{
            "_id":"WPg2zdgdMsBxsge7",
            "title":"Son Of A Preacher Man",
            "artists":[
               {
                  "_id":"WgCuwalktE9Wl4bS",
                  "display_name":"Dusty Springfield"
               }
            ],
            "sources":[
               {
                  "album":"At Her Very Best",
                  "length":144241,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:02hv6aR5wa2Vhw4Xo8DaN2",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Dusty In Memphis",
                  "length":149365,
                  "uris":[
                     "deezer:track:1104538",
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "isrc:USAT20702465",
                     "spotify:track:1IYeYU3r8CkP9ECrhdX9en",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:26EuE0OC3dbqcpIyIvS13O",
                     "spotify:track:28jBolSSfkXDYYOZWTcHDE",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:4UCIi4gRVUG7x4nFGQiKmo",
                     "spotify:track:5TbLONSGZsR8cbhNEodCH6"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"The Silver Collection",
                  "length":147823,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:0kHzYqfLwnfObM1v4E6LGI",
                     "spotify:track:0scrtPmtlIVwwk9s4LXJ8n",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:4UCIi4gRVUG7x4nFGQiKmo"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Dusty In Memphis [Deluxe Edition]",
                  "length":149365,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:USAT20702465",
                     "spotify:track:7odHgoLFi3GQ90E9PeraI3"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"PULP FICTION Collector's Edition",
                  "length":146620,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:1rojMZ3XzgmAZhc5PpVDec",
                     "spotify:track:3iDaK0Vsw1jRfuGjGBVU25",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:43MOKEiRYA05XEGnjnkMgS",
                     "spotify:track:55iXg89f5nRwBeFI39FX1p"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Drivetime",
                  "length":144895,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:1rojMZ3XzgmAZhc5PpVDec",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:4b3YH93d0kEJ5lVvFtkiLP"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"110% Oldies",
                  "length":145391,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:0kDT8dYWwdvuwfApPSU3TP",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:3EqAYYYyhCYWebfA06CRBg",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Dusty Springfield Hit Pac - 5 Series",
                  "length":144215,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:24IavnnaGG2AGYMdAwmVdn",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Movies",
                  "length":143953,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:4gYl9m2oErJgwY2cu2TsuB",
                     "spotify:track:79awzAL3IzFfvo60KvAuIC"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Just Sing",
                  "length":146000,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:1pWd0ar7Y77ex8fWfaAyiq",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:4gYl9m2oErJgwY2cu2TsuB",
                     "spotify:track:65QTLn5NbBvLkR1U9aaHLA"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"100 Essential Hits - Woman",
                  "length":144000,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:2QLTd3D6Cb79rbPMMxVkRo",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:55iXg89f5nRwBeFI39FX1p",
                     "spotify:track:7B4UpODwurpp47tbnpsRSb"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"True Drivetime (3 CD Set )",
                  "length":145000,
                  "uris":[
                     "deezer:track:910223",
                     "isrc:GBF086800754"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"100 Soul",
                  "length":146000,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:09crwvurlODl7CYY7Tv1Ku",
                     "spotify:track:25jzJ7xqVTMsG4DAR50W48"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "album":"Just Dusty",
                  "length":145000,
                  "uris":[
                     "isrc:GBF086800754",
                     "spotify:track:0knTTHUdnVn5CSblhcw7bS",
                     "spotify:track:0scrtPmtlIVwwk9s4LXJ8n",
                     "spotify:track:3zRliQqUlisnnl3BguDkZM",
                     "spotify:track:6gmeXarVRe4ZBBKjXepRAC",
                     "spotify:track:7odHgoLFi3GQ90E9PeraI3"
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "status":"normal",
   "tags":[
      "minecraft"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is JSON format, or at least it looks like it, there are java parsers for JSON so try using it, it will produce Map, not an array